# What does ? mean in php when reading and interpreting a URL

Tags: php

My system works flawlessly, my questions is mainly academic.

Here is my situation. I built a helpdesk for this company.

The helpdesk simulates URL's by adding a

```
~.php?id=123
```

I can get the value from the id in that URL by using the superglobal GET and then showing the right solution according to the ID displayed on the URL.

```
$value_of_id = $_GET('id');
```

I never understood though, what does the question mark in the url below mean.

```
http://myhost.php?id=123-abc
```

If anybody that knows the theory well can explain me what that is, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: The same as it does in any web language: it's the separator between the page name and any query arguments being passed to that page - See section 3.2.2 of the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc2616)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

3.3. HTTP

An HTTP URL takes the form:

```
  http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
```

...

```
   Within the <path> and <searchpart> components, "/", ";", "?" are
   reserved.  The "/" character may be used within HTTP to designate a
   hierarchical structure.
```

So as others mentioned it is only a reserved separator there.

This document updates the above (as DaveRandom mentions):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4

But I think the point is the same, and it is harder to quote from this newer version. :)

Comment: How may the `;` be used? Or what is it's purpose? This is very interesting.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 is the relevant resource for the general URI syntax.

Answer (score 3):

It's the separator between the resource (PHP document) and the parameter string.

Comment: This actually is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is only used to separate the URL from the query string. Since you can't separate it using a slash (beacuse it would have been a folder) it has been decided to use the question tag. I don't think it has got a grate importance as a symbol.