# What going on in this php link?

Tags: php

''http://example.mobi/main.php?video=1768812741'' What are the numbers after '='? Is it a file name like .php or .html file or its a media file like .mp4?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Also: [What does ? mean in php when reading and interpreting a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20975146)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP link is fairly normal, and you will see more like it if you pay close attention to the URLs in your browser window.

What the link does, is, it calls the script `main.php`, with the argument `video=1768812741`, which can be translated in understandable English as: 'Hey file main.php, please load a video with the following ID (identifier): 1768812741'. So the URL just loads a video with a predefined ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass on variables with the HTTP GET protocol.
After the name of the referred page (*main.php*) you put a `?` mark, so that you can specify the variables.

On the page, *video* is accessibly through the `$_GET['video']` property.

Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: and avoid links to w3shools, famously bad

Comment: Well, thats why I changed my answer even before the first comment on it. I also noted, that I understood, however, I dont see that comment anymore.